# AVFoundation, AVAudioSessionRouteChange incorrect behavior on IOS 11.4.1

Tags: ios, avfoundation, airplay

I subscribe on notification from AVAudioSessionRouteChange

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,  
                                               selector: #selector(handleRouteChange),  
                                               name: .AVAudioSessionRouteChange,  
                                               object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())  

@objc func handleRouteChange(_ notification: Notification) { 

}
```

When I push content to Airplay I get notify from `.AVAudioSessionRouteChange`, but when I try return to play on my application notify does not coming. In `IOS <= 11.4` it work ok.

Maybe anyone has the same problem, please help resolve.

Comment: Hi Dmitry. I faced the same issue today. It is reproducible in iOS 12 also. Did you find any other way to get notifications when routing is changed from AirPlay back to device?